# Docker Swarm: docker stack deploy fails when executed second time

Tags: docker, cluster-computing, docker-swarm, docker-registry, swarm

I have a single node docker swarm which has just been created with `docker swarm init`.

I have a docker-stack.yml which contains the following deployment:

```
version: '3.3'

services:

  website:
    image: docker.pkg.github.com/foo/bar/bar:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    environment:
      HOST: bar.com
    secrets:
      - site.key
      - site.cert
    networks:
      - foo-net

networks:
  foo-net:
    driver: overlay
    external: true

secrets:
  site.key:
    external: true
  site.cert:
    external: true
```

First, I login into the registry and it tells me that the **login was successful**.
Second, I deploy the stack

```
$ docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth --compose-file docker-stack.yml foo
 Creating service foo_bar
```

After that, the service is running and everything works as expected.

However, when I try to deploy a stack with the same command a **second time** (a few seconds later), it fails with the following message.

```
$ docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth --compose-file docker-stack.yml foo
Updating service foo_website (id: uvtqpdx74784dy9egj5i1c7sb)
image docker.pkg.github.com/foo/bar/bar:latest could not be accessed on a registry to record
its digest. Each node will access docker.pkg.github.com/foo/bar/bar:latest independently,
possibly leading to different nodes running different
versions of the image
```

Why does this happen?

All networks and secrets are created beforehand and my docker version is:

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:           19.03.6
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.17
 Git commit:        369ce74a3c
 Built:             Fri Feb 28 23:45:43 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.6
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.17
  Git commit:       369ce74a3c
  Built:            Wed Feb 19 01:06:16 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.3.3-0ubuntu1~18.04.2
  GitCommit:        
 runc:
  Version:          spec: 1.0.1-dev
  GitCommit:        
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:
```

I appreciate any help!
Thanks

Comment: Does the deploy command actually fail? I've the same issue with a stack of mine, but I just ignore the warning (because I don't use replication for that particular stack)

Comment: Yes, ist fails as no updates are applied.